# Drupal module to make html pages of all nodes automatically

Tags: nodes, performance

I am looking for a solution / module which can create the whole site in HTML .

So every time the user does content changes, he can click on a button, it will create the html for that node only or the whole site and syncs it to an FTP or same hosting.

I do not want to use caching or any other technique to speed up the site.

is it possible with drupal ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Boost module](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) is the closest thing to 'Drupal as a static generator'.

> Boost provides static page caching for Drupal enabling a very significant performance and scalability boost for sites that receive mostly anonymous traffic.

**EDIT**: You could also look at the [Static module](https://www.drupal.org/project/static). However it doesn't provide a mechanism to get the files onto a server, you would need to set that up separately.

Comment: Also the Static module: https://www.drupal.org/project/static

Comment: okay, but there will be no PHP executed once the site loads.or DB queries  ? No Drupal Cron runs or cache is rebuilt ? etc ..

Comment: Boost runs next to a functional Drupal install, so if someone is logging in there will be PHP and DB.

Static will not run any PHP or other Drupal stuff.